# build gccgo got linker error

Tags: go, gccgo

I am building gccgo given the instruction [here](https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo). However, I got error message after I did:

```
../gccgo/configure --prefix=/opt/gccgo --enable-languages=c,c++,go --with-ld=/opt/gold/bin/ld  
make
```

Error:

> /opt/gold/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lugin
>   /opt/gold/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lugin-opt=/home/objdir/./gcc/lto-wrapper
>   /opt/gold/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc9M7ZGm.res

Here is what source code I used:

os: ubuntu 14.04/x86_64
binutils: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.29.tar.xz
gccgo code brach: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/gccgo

Is there anything that I missed?

**Update**: It works for me after I remove the `--with-ld==/opt/gold/bin/ld` option when running configure for gccgo make. Seems this is an issue related to gold.

Comment: A typo somewhere in LDFLAGS.

Comment: Yeah, probably supposed to be `--plugin` and got converted to `-lugin` (-p) accidentally deleted?  Gold uses `--plugin` and `--plugin-opt=...`

Comment: Are you saying "-lugin" is the typo? Unfortunately, this is the exact error message I got.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `--enable-plugins` to `configure` when you build binutils to be able to use plugins with `ld.gold` (the plugin interface is enabled by default for new enough versions of `ld.bfd`, the traditional GNU linker).

See this bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22500